# jsPDF html option generates huge PDF file sizes with images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, png, jspdf

I was using Puppeteer to generate PDF from HTML and file size with 10 png images where 300 Kb. I had to find another solution that works from the client-side so used jsPDF. Now the same HTML generates a PDF of size 23 Mb. Below is my code, Since I am using the compress option it's 23 MB, if not 26 MB. All my PNGs are altogether not even 1 MB. PDF is generated perfectly. Good results except for the large size!!

```
const doc = new jsPDF({ compress: true });
        doc.setDisplayMode(1);        
        doc.html(html, {
          callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save(
              `${process.env.REACT_APP_NAME}_${new Date().toTimeString()}`
            );
            setMode("html");
            dispatch(hideLoaderUI());
          },
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          html2canvas: { scale: 0.25 },
        });
```

A surprising fact is when I used pt as a unit, 9 page PDF became 4 pages [Zoomed out] and still, the size was the same.

Looks like the images are causing the issue. I removed all the images and the PDF became 200 KB. My HTML has base64 png images. Enabled 1 image which shows 32 Kb on the disk, and the PDF size shoot to 3800+ KB. Why?

Comment: I tried the available option to control the quality of the image by adding image: { type: "png", quality: 0.1 },. No change at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: I am going to try their code locally and try to see what's going on. I hope someone from jsPDF community has some answers.

Comment: same problem, did you get any solution?
 By adding  4 images my pdf shoots to 5Mb. Also tried {type:"jpeg",quality:0.4} doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?